# How do I display 3 recent posts in footer with Timber?

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

So, I am beating my head over this for 2 days now. How do I display 3 recent posts in footer using Timber and Twig? I am using a starter theme from Timber.
What I did inside my footer.php file:

```
$timberContext = $GLOBALS['timberContext'];
if ( ! isset( $timberContext ) ) {
throw new \Exception( 'Timber context not set in footer.' );
}
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 3,
);
$timberContext['featured'] = new Timber\PostQuery($args);
$templates = array( 'page-plugin.twig');
$timberContext['content'] = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
Timber::render( $templates, $timberContext );
```

And inside my footer.twig I tried displaying them:

```
<ul class = "featured-posts-list">
    {% for post in featured %}
        <li><a href="{{ post.link }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Now the problem is it displays nothing. If I replace featured with posts in footer.twig, it displays whatever posts are on the current page. It seems to me that Timber doesn't process my post query and I don't know why is that. I was looking for an answer but didn't find one. Also, this is my first post here, so I am sorry in advance if it is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just found the answer to my own question :) In case someone has a similar problem, I resolved it by adding the variable to the context inside functions.php:

```
public function add_to_context( $context ) {
        //...previous variables...
        //the one I have added
        $context['featured'] = new Timber\PostQuery(array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
        ));
        return $context;
    }
```

Then inside my footer.twig I use it like this:

```
<ul class = "featured-posts-list">
    {% for post in featured %}
        <li><a href="{{ post.link }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```